# Website displays old version of page

Tags: database, cache

So I'm working on a website for a company and everytime I edit a page/post I have to manually go in to the database and remove the old versions (which isn't something that I'd like to do since it's pretty good to have) just so the website can update the front-end to be the same as the back-ends current version.

Is this caused by WordPress (v 4.0) or is it some kind of cache? (No cache-plugin installed however).

Comment: Did you clear browser caches. Did you test the site in another browser. Don't you have any custom caches or transients set that might have an influence. What happens if you disable all plugins and switch to a bundled theme? Also, turn debugging on and look at server logs for any possible bug that might be causing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced similar issue while working for a client. The issue may cause due to following reasons.

- Check server configuration and server cache. ( This happens if you are using specialized wordpress hosting; the server admin configured some cache mechanism to increase performance) In this case you have to wait till the sever refresh its cache.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it was the hosting who made some cache-ing. Thanks!

Comment: You can also contact your host's tech support and have them clear/disable the server-side cache. We just had this problem with justhost.com, who turn on server-side caching by default on their shared hosting. They disabled the server-side cache after clearing it.